# convert from sas to R

Tags: r, sas

I m new with R, and I want to convert this  SAS macro  to R :

```
%Macro NumericToString(var,lenString);

/* Convert A NUMERIC variable TO STRING */
/* @Var : NAME OF  THE NUMERIC VARIABLE THAT WE WANT TO CONVERT ON  STRING*/
/*@LenString : NEW LENGTH OF THE STRING VARIABLE*/

%global newlabel;

LENGTH &var._n $ &LenString.;
&var._n=put(&var.,&LenString.);
if &var.=. then &var._n=''; /* Gestion des valeurs manquantes */
call symput('newlabel',vlabel(&var.));/* On garde le label de l'ancienne variable ' */
label &var._n = "&newlabel."; 
drop &var.;
rename &var._n=&var.;
%Mend;
```

Please I need help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Currently, your question is poorly formatted and very hard to read. Also, your comments are in french. If you fix this it will be easier to answer your questions.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I have suggested a few edits and as mentioned by mhh, your comments could also be in English. Also, I guess your code is missing a couple of lines. Without a datastep, the above would make no changes or technically not run.

Comment: Without know how it's used this is pretty impossible in this use case. You likely need a new function in R but without knowing the other steps, this would be pretty hard to generalize. In general, I do not recommend line by line conversion, ideally you understand the full process and then migrate it to R. Harder to do in the real world sometimes but unfortunately this one of the cases where a line by line conversion would be impossible.

Comment: Do you want to convert the existing SAS code (which probably does not do what you want because of mistakes in the timing of when the macro variables NEW_LABLE is created and when it is used)?  Or do you want to convert the spirit of what the macro is probably trying to do?   Why not just google how to convert a number to a string in R code?